# homogeneous transformation matrix - How to use it?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am trying to understand the homogeneous transformation matrix, for which i don't understand what kind of input it requires.

[image]

What bothering me is the subscript (new) used at the "Location of old Origin". 
What origin do they want me to put in, and why. ?

Answer (score 1):

See the following picture:

[image]

I ignored the rotation part, assuming you understand that. The "Location of Old Origin" with subscript "new" means the $x,y$ value of the old origin under the new coordinate system. In the picture, we want to find the new coordinates of the point, which is the old coordinates of it plus the old origin's coordinates under new system. For example, let the old coordinates of the point be $(2,1)$, the new coordinates of the old origin be $(-1,3)$, then the new coordinates of the point is $(2+(-1), 1+3)=(1,4)$.

In this example, you should put
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
in the "Location of Old Origin" with subscript "new" section.

The whole formula is for you to find the new coordinates of a point $S$ from its old coordinates. In the above example, 
$$S_{\text{old}}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}, S_{\text{new}}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

If there is rotation with angle $\theta$, the matrix looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{new}\\y_{new}\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta & -1\\\sin\theta&\cos \theta& 3\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_{old}\\y_{old}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence,
$$x_{new}=\cos \theta x_{old} -\sin\theta y_{old}-1\\
y_{new}=\sin\theta x_{old}+\cos\theta y_{old}+3$$

See the $cos, sin$ part takes care of the rotation, the $-1, +3$ takes care of the translation of the coordinate system.

Comment: So it is just a summation of the old origin and new origin....
does the summation shift the old origin towards the new or how should it understood ?

Comment: @user154311: I edited. See if you understand it now.

Comment: Whats confusing me is whether you are talking about i point in the coordinate frame , or the origin within the cordinate frame itself... sorry for being  demanding...

Comment: @user154311: In the example, $(-1, 3)$ is the $x,y$ value of the origin, but adding that to the coordinates of the point, gives you the new coordinates of the point. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: ok.. So in my case i know the origin of the old and origin of new coordinate frame..  

So which one should i use...

Comment: @user154311: What do you mean by "you know the origin of the old, and the origin of new"? Either one has to be a point under a specified system. What it is asking is the origin of the old, as a point under the new coordinate system. I changed my picture in the answer. So $O_{new}$ is the origin now, we are seeking the coordinates of $O_{old}$, which is $(-1,3)$ in my example.

Comment: "What it is asking is the origin of the old, as a point under the new coordinate system." Based on that definition (2,1) is a point in old coordinate frame, and (-1,3) is the origin of the old coordinate frame, in the new coordinate frame. How would you retrieve that.. In your case that information is given beforehand, as I understand it. 


I know a point in the old coordinate frame and new coordinate frame, and their origins. 
But i don't know the origin of the old  coordinate frame in the new coordinate frame.

Comment: @user154311: If you know a point in the old coordinate frame, that is $S_{old}$, and in new coordinate frame, that is $S_{new}$, then $S_{new}-S_{old}$ would give you the old origin under the new coordinate frame.